# WebView - Adding a label to display status

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I am using the following code with `java 8` using `javaFx`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class Highlighter extends Application {

    private boolean marked;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html");

        final TextField searchField = new TextField("light");
        searchField.setPromptText("Enter the text you would like to highlight and press ENTER to highlight");
        searchField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                if (engine.getDocument() != null) {
                    highlight(
                            engine,
                            searchField.getText()
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        final Button highlightButton = new Button("Highlight");
        highlightButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        highlightButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                searchField.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
            }
        });
        final Button markedButton = new Button("Mark it");
        markedButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
               marked = true;
            }
        });
        markedButton.setCancelButton(true);

        HBox controls = new HBox(10);
        controls.getChildren().setAll(
                highlightButton,
                markedButton
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().setAll(searchField, controls, webView);
        searchField.setMinHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        controls.setMinHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        controls.disableProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().runningProperty());
        searchField.disableProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().runningProperty());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        primaryStage.show();

        webView.requestFocus();
    }

    private void highlight(WebEngine engine, String text) {
        engine.executeScript("$('body').removeHighlight().highlight('" + text + "')");
    }

}
```

My problem is I want to add a label which displays the `marked status` of a page.

I tried simply adding a `Label label = new Label("Marked: " + marked)` to the `controls`, but this does not work.

Any recommendations how I could add a label to my code to display the `marked status`?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `Label` to controls with your actual code:

```
private boolean marked;

Label label = new Label("Marked: " + marked)
controls.getChildren().setAll(
            highlightButton,
            markedButton,
            label
);
```

it will always show `Marked: false`, no matter if you change `marked` afterwards.

If you want that your control responds to changes, JavaFX has *observable* properties, as you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).

So you can replace the boolean primitive with this property that wraps the boolean value:

```
private final BooleanProperty marked=new SimpleBooleanProperty();
```

Create the label:

```
    Label label=new Label("Marked: "+marked.get());
    HBox controls = new HBox(10);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    controls.getChildren().setAll(
            highlightButton,
            markedButton,
            label
    );
```

Change the event for `markedButton`:

```
    markedButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
           marked.set(true);
        }
    });
```

(this will work just once, since for now you don't have implemented a way to reset `marked` to false again)

And finally, add a listener for any change in`marked` property:

```
    marked.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            label.setText("Marked: "+newValue);
        }
    });
```

Instead of the listener, you can also use `Bindings`:

```
Label label=new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Marked: ").concat(marked));
```

Comment: I get `BooleanProperty cannot be resolved to a type`. Any libary you are using or is this standart javafx?

Comment: It's standard JavaFX, and if you are using Java 8 it should be there. Try to import this package: `javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty` and check it compiles. On the contrary, under Java 7 (JavaFX 2.2) you need to add jfxrt.jar to the classpath.

Comment: Thx. Finally I get `The method concat(String) is undefined for the type Bindings`. Any idea what`s wrong with that?

Comment: Make sure you use this package: `import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;`